# Cannot 'run as administrator' from desktop shortcuts in Windows 7!

Tags: windows-7, elevation

On my Windows 7 system I can select a program shortcut in the start menu, right click on it and select 'Run as administrator'. I then get the confirmation prompt and the application starts up with elevated privileges.

However, if I copy any of these shortcuts to my desktop, right click and select 'Run as administrator' nothing happens! No prompt, no error message nothing. I have tested this on a friends Windows 7 machine and it works.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This little "how to" shows how to run automaticaly shortcuts with administrative privileges.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/always-start-an-application-in-administrator-mode-on-windows-vista/

> All shortcuts in Windows since Vista have a special property that you can set that will allow the application to run as Administrator. This works perfectly for creating a batch file to restart a service, for instance.

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem I am seeing so I cannot accept it but it does provide me with a work around. Thanks